# Remove Tooltip from Slider Control in WinRT XAML

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, xaml, windows-runtime

Is there a way to remove the tooltip from the slider control in WinRT XAML? This is what I am referring to:

[image: tooltip]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set this  **IsThumbToolTipEnabled="False"** to your Slider.

Comment: Is it possible to make the tooltip always visible. Now it will show only when the user tap it, but I want that to be visible always.